# Double count on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
create table creations (id int)
create table images (creation_id int, path varchar)
```

In the `images.path`, there is a limited number of possible values, like 'my documents', 'desktop', etc (it's a datamining DB).

I want to find the number of different paths for a creation, and how many of those creations have this number of paths.

With this data:

```
insert into creations (id) values (1), (2), (3), (4)
insert into images (creation_id, path) values
(1, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'a'), --creation 1: 1 path
(2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'a'), --creation 2: 2 paths
(3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), --creation 3: 3 paths
(4, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (4, 'b') --creation 4: 3 paths
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
nb_paths | nb_creations
-----------------------
1        | 1
2        | 2
3        | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand the question, nor why you have supplied an query as an answer.

However all I would suggest is moving the correlated query into an APPLY. Below I have used OUTER APPLY which would allow all creation records even if not found in paths. A CROSS APPLY would limit results to only creations found in paths.

```
SELECT
    nb_path
  , COUNT(*) AS nb_creations
FROM (
        SELECT
            c.id
          , COALESCE(oa.nb_path, 0) nb_path
        FROM creations AS c
            OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT
                        COUNT(DISTINCT [path])
                    FROM images AS i
                    WHERE i.creation_id = c.id
                ) OA (nb_path)
        ) AS g
GROUP BY
    nb_path
;
```

COALESCE() is  *{or ISNULL() could be}* used in case a creation exists without a path. That wouldn't be required with CROSS APPLY.

---

**NB:** The APPLY operator is unique to MS SQL Server (at time of writing)

I understand similar functionality is (or will be) through

CROSS JOIN LATERAL

and this is present in Oracle 12c

Comment: With my data, it gives the same results, so what is (are) the benefit(s) of using `apply` ?

Comment: it is part of the FROM clause, which is performed at the beginning of the query (unlike the select clause which is performed toward the end of a query). In SQL Server this has benefits for the optimizer. As an added bonus the data referenced this way can be referenced by its alias throughout the query. (Perhaps not such a bonus for this query, but it can be). If really interested try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m426WYclz8 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goyWzAu-AA0

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to understand it and keep it in my toolbox :)

Answer (score 1):

It works if I first count the number of `path`s for each creation, then group on this, by using the results as a table:

```
select nb_path, COUNT(*) as nb_creations
from (
    select c.id,
    (
        select count(distinct [path])
        from images as i
        where i.creation_id = c.id
    ) as nb_path
    from creations as c
) as g
group by nb_path
```

Comment: You might want to put this in question ??

Comment: If this is the answer of your own question i find it not very helpful for future readers(which is the sole reason for such answers). It's very specific and is not explained.

Comment: Well, I wanted to try out the "answer you own question, q&a style" feature, but you can point me to guidelines about this.

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com has references regarding self-answering questions  I believe. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=self-answer

Answer (score -2):

```
select cnt nb_paths, count(cnt) nb_creations from (
select count(distinct i.path) cnt from 
creations c join images i
on c.id = i.creation_id
group by i.creation_id)A group by cnt
```

First rollup by creation_id and then rollup by counts.

Comment: Doesn't work ; it returns the possible paths, and "1" for each.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I beg to disagree. If the answer solves the problem, it is an answer. Why would an explanation be mandatory if the code is simple enough.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti: well it's not what I want either. For each possible path, it lists the number of creations using it. I'll update my question with some sample data.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti explanation is useful for people trying to understand the solution.  No one is asking you to explain what every line does, but provide some description of **why** the solution works and how it relates to the problem at hand.  It might be simple to you, but it may not be simple to the OP or someone who encounters your answer in future while researching their own problem.  You are not just answering questions for the original asker, but for **everyone** who has the same problem and comes to Stack Overflow for help.

Comment: @downvoters: May I know why this answer is **still** down voted even when I have given the requisite clarification. Also, I believe the answer is fine and it doesn't deserve downvotes.

Comment: Yep now it does what I want, with one less select.